# Send SMS Messages using Python

Tags: python, sms, smtplib, kannel

I found an interesting post to [send sms](http://alextrle.blogspot.com/2011/05/how-to-send-sms-message-with-python.html) using python. I didn't check the possibility of this. Glad to get your comments on using `smtplib` for sending sms.

Any way I need to use an open source gateway like [kannel](http://kannel.org/index.shtml) for sending sms. Can this code be modified to use with Kannel or else please let me have some good tutorials to use Kannel for sending sms using python.

Comment: Try this: http://www.rapidsms.org/en/latest/topics/backends/kannel.html

Comment: @adamr: Thanks adamr, I'll try this one!

Comment: Megan from Twilio here. I got started on Twilio-Python before joining the company: https://www.twilio.com/docs/python/install